# C++ __imp_ prefix

Tags: c++, windows, dllimport, dllexport, name-mangling

Although I see it mentioned everywhere that the `__imp_` prefix is prepended to symbols for exported functions within a DLL (with the `__imp_` version resolving directly into the IAT), I have never found any documentation on the matter, I have simply been relying on the words of others.

Is it every defined that symbols export two versions of themselves in any official documentation? Or did people simply figure this out by disassembling PE files produced by common linkers?

Relatedly, is there a reason why linkers have decided to create two versions of the same symbol? Why not just have the non-`__imp_` version be the one which resolves into the IAT of the executable, while still making the code which references the symbol within the DLL use `dllimport`?

Also, I have seen a wide range of "imp" prefixes used, including `_imp_`, `_imp__`, `__imp__`, and of course `__imp_`. Which one is technically "correct"? (or are they different depending on the linker?).

Comment: I thought the mention of PE files implied what OS I was targeting. I guess I will also add a tag.

Comment: "Why not just have the non-`__imp_` version be the one which resolves into the IAT of the executable, while still making the code which references the symbol within the DLL use `dllimport`?" The hard part is the second half: Making sure all references to the symbol use `dllimport`. Anybody who forgets will end up jumping into data and crashing with a NX exception.